Optimal Way to Register Customizer Options in a WordPress Theme: One Hook or Multiple Hooks?
I am relatively new to WordPress theme development, and I want to add options to the WordPress Customizer. I am considering two different methods to register Customizer settings and controls, but I'm unsure which one is more optimal.
Method 1:
In this approach, I register a single hook in the index.php file and include the required files.
<?php
if (!function_exists('mytheme_customizer')) {
    function mytheme_customizer(WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize): void {
        require_once MYTHEME_DIR . '/inc/customizer/breadcrumb-customizer.php';
        // other include files
    }
}
add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_customizer');

Method 2:
In this approach, each file registers its own hook independently.
breadcrumb-customizer.php
<?php
if (!function_exists('mytheme_breadcrumb_customizer')) {
    function mytheme_breadcrumb_customizer(WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize): void {
        // code
    }
}
add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_breadcrumb_customizer');

abc-customizer.php
<?php
if (!function_exists('mytheme_abc_customizer')) {
    function mytheme_abc_customizer(WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize): void {
        // code
    }
}
add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_abc_customizer');

...
I have tried both methods, and I personally prefer Method 2 because it keeps the Customizer options modular and organized. However, I have noticed that many themes on WordPress.org tend to use Method 1.
I am concerned that registering hooks in multiple files (Method 2) might be less efficient or slower. I would like to understand the reasons behind the preference for Method 1 in many themes and determine which method is more optimal in terms of performance and best practices.

If your theme is expected to grow in future and you value the modularity and maintainability, then Method 2 is a good option. The performance impact is minimal, and the organizational benefits outweigh the potential drawbacks, if you prefer simplicity and working on a smaller project, then Method 1 is perfectly fine for you.
Basically the choice depends on your specific needs you have and the scale of your project.
